# Case Statement with complex AND/OR not working as intended

Tags: t-sql

I am expecting this to return the value of 'C', but it is returning 'A'.  I cannot seem to figure out why this will not work as my logic looks sound.

```
DECLARE @WeekStartDay varchar(10)
DECLARE @WeekEndDay varchar(10)
SET @WeekStartDay = 'Saturday'
SET @WeekEndDay = 'Saturday'



SELECT

    CASE

        WHEN (
                ((@WeekStartDay = 'Saturday') OR (@WeekStartDay = 'Sunday'))
                         AND 
                ((@WeekEndDay <> 'Saturday') OR (@WeekEndDay <> 'Sunday'))
            )
            THEN 'A'

        WHEN (
                ((@WeekEndDay = 'Saturday') OR (@WeekEndDay = 'Sunday'))
                        AND 
                ((@WeekStartDay <> 'Saturday') OR (@WeekStartDay <> 'Sunday'))
            )
            THEN 'B'
        WHEN (
                ((@WeekEndDay = 'Saturday') OR (@WeekEndDay = 'Sunday'))
                        AND 
                ((@WeekStartDay = 'Saturday') OR (@WeekStartDay = 'Sunday'))
            ) 
            THEN 'C'

    END AS Result
```

My intended function is:

I am trying to get it to deteremine

IF the @WeekStartDay = Saturday or Sunday AND @WeekEndDay IS NOT Saturday or Sunday THEN 'A'

IF the @WeekEndDay = Saturday or Sunday AND @WeekStartDay IS NOT Saturday or Sunday THEN 'B'

IF @WeekStartDay AND @WeekEndDay BOTH = Saturday or Sunday THEN 'C'

Hmmm from responses looks like my logic was way more off than I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting the parameter values in as literals gives (for the first case)

```
         WHEN ((('Saturday' = 'Saturday')  OR ('Saturday' = 'Sunday'))
                           AND 
               (( 'Saturday' <> 'Saturday') OR ( 'Saturday' <> 'Sunday')))
```

Which is

```
         WHEN ((True OR False) AND (False OR True))
```

Which is

```
         WHEN (True AND True)
```

Which is

```
         WHEN (True)
```

I think you need

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN @WeekStartDay IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN 
        CASE WHEN @WeekEndDay IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN 
            'C'
        ELSE 
            'A'
        END 
    ELSE 
        CASE WHEN @WeekEndDay IN ('Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN 
            'B'
        ELSE 
            NULL /*You haven't said what should happen here?*/
        END 
    END
 AS Result
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is a huge help! Oh wow, Yeah, that makes a lot more sense nesting the case statements like that and using IN. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

AND means when both conditions are true, OR means when either condition is true.

`@WeekStartDay` is "Saturday". 
`@WeekEndDay` is "Saturday".

Therefore if you start breaking it all down:

```
A: (TRUE OR FALSE) AND (FALSE OR TRUE) = TRUE AND TRUE = TRUE
```

`A` wins because it is the first condition to match your requirements.

You'll have to explain further what you are trying to do, because I cannot see what I'd need to do to help fix the code.

Comment: I am trying to get it to deteremine

IF the @WeekStartDay = Saturday or Sunday AND @WeekEndDay IS NOT Saturday or Sunday THEN 'A'
IF the @WeekEndDay = Saturday or Sunday AND @WeekStartDay IS NOT Saturday or Sunday THEN 'B'
IF @WeekStartDay AND @WeekEndDay BOTH = Saturday or Sunday THEN 'C'


Hmmm, looks like my logic was way more off than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

(@WeekEndDay <> 'Saturday') OR (@WeekEndDay <> 'Sunday') is the problem.

That will always return true.

Case B: has the same issue with

(@WeekStartDay <> 'Saturday') OR (@WeekStartDay <> 'Sunday')